# Projecting a Transparent image in blender

Tags: camera, project

I am trying to project an image(PNG) with some transparent area onto a plane in the blender, but the alpha area is black. Is there any way to make it transparent?[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your alpha is connected and your **Blend Mode** is set to something other than *Opaque*:

[image: Alpha]